# Как получить с помощью селектора блок, в котором есть определенные элементы?

Tags: jquery, css

Как сделать jquery выборку (селектор):

Все дивы с классом `Foo` у которых есть дочерние элементы `span` или `p`.

Comment: Поменяйте заголовок вопроса на осмысленный. Система не просто там заставляет вас ввести минимум 15 символов.

Comment: Почему нужен осмысленный заголовок: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.Foo>span, div.Foo>p").parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.write(
  $("div.Foo:has(span, p)").length +
  '<br>' +
  $("div.Foo:has(>span, >p)").length
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=Foo><p></div>
<div class=Foo><span></span></div>
<div class=Foo><a></a></div>
<div><p></div>
<div><span></span></div>
<div class=Foo><div><p></div></div>
<div class=Foo><div><span></span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял то: `$('.Foo > span, .Foo > p').parent()`

он выберет те .Foo в которых лежит `span/p` на прямую, без вложенности, за это отвечает оператор `>`, если надо выбрать все существующие (не только вложенные именно в .Foo), то можешь убрать оператор